# rewriting $_GET to a multi-tier directory: blah/blahblah

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a field in my database called product-url.

It might look like this:

```
Company-Name/Product-Name-Here
```

And I have a rewrite rule to make nice urls out of that field.

```
<a href="/products/$product-url">productname</a>

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?product-url=$1 [L]
```

Then I do:

```
if (isset($_GET['product-url'])) {
    look up + display that items information
}
```

But when I click my link I'm getting 'page not found'.

Is the slash in my product-url field tricking/making the RewriteRule break? If so, is there a way around it?

Thank you for any help...

Comment: Your pattern demands for a slash on the end of the address, but your client-side URL doesn’t have one.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the tip. I just tried removing that slash (it is now "^products/(.*)$" - but now I get a 500 Internal Server Error trying to load my page.

Comment: What does the server’s error log have to say about it?

Comment: File does not exist: C:/..../htdocs/products/Company-Name, referer: http://localhost/products/

Comment: And when I click on my php generated link, it just says site.com/products/company-name/product-name-here was not found. It's like the rewrite isn't happening for some reason.

Comment: Then you should get a normal 404, not a 500.

Comment: ^products/(.*)$ /products/index.php?product-url=$1 gives me the 500 Error, whereas with ^products/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?product-url=$1 the script seems to work, though it doesn't find my product because I don't have that last slash in it.

Comment: It *appears* to be working if I add the final '/' to my product-url field in the database (ie, company-name/product-name/)...really didn't want that there, though...

Answer (score 1):

Add a trailing slash on your hrefs and keep the original RewriteRule.

```
<a href="/products/$product-url/">productname</a>

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/$ /products/index.php?product-url=$1 [L]
```

If you change the RewriteRule to be only `^products/(.*)$`, it would match the `/products/index.php` itself, so it creates a loop, thus a 500 error.

---

Another way without changing the hrefs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /products/index.php?product-url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yeah, I ended up adding a trailing slash to the product-url field in my database and it started working :)